# Fuzzy textbooks

Tags: references, fuzzy

From what you have read or heard about, which is a good book on fuzzy logic/sets/systems? I'm interested in basic of fuzzy systems, fuzzification/defuzzification, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is the best book I would recomend for the subject: [Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic: Theory and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131011715) by George J. Klir.

Here is an easy to read book: [Fuzzy Logic: The Revolutionary Computer Technology that Is Changing Our World](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671875353) by Dan McNeill.

Besides here are a list of links that might help:

[Fuzzy Logic Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20101210171047/http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/mar98/fuz/flindex.html).

[Fuzzy Logic](http://www.fuzzy-logic.com/)

Video lecture on [Fuzzy Logic](http://videolectures.net/acai05_berthold_fl/) by Michael Berthold, Department of Computer and Information Science, University of Konstanz.

Comment: I second Mariana's 1st recommendation (i.e. Klir, George J. and Yuan, Bo, 1995, Fuzzy sets and Fuzzy Logic: Theory and Applications. Prentice Hall: Upper Saddle River, N.J.). I got lucky and found a copy on Amazon for about $1. It's chock full of hard-core math, but after slogging through it, I was able to implement many different types of fuzzy sets quite easily. If you're looking to complement Klir and Yuan with a readable text that explains the interesting concepts behind fuzzy sets, the most useful one I've found to date is McNeill, Dan, 1993, Fuzzy Logic. Simon & Schuster: New York.

Comment: Another endorsement of Klir and Yuan. They really help explain the often confusing (for me) way that notation and nomenclature are used in the literature.

Answer (score 4):

I have no experience with fuzzy things (well, apart from [Fuzzy Felt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_Felt)) but this book looks interesting:

Buckley, James J. *Fuzzy probability and statistics*. Springer, 2006. ISBN [9783540308416](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ABookSources&isbn=9783540308416).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for exhaustiveness, Springer has the [Handbook of Fuzzy Systems](http://www.springer.com/series/5997?detailsPage=titles) series which covers most topics. I particularly recommend [Fundamentals of Fuzzy Sets](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780792377320) edited by Dubois & Prade which was particularly helpful to me when I was taking a graduate class in uncertainty modelling & possibility theory (with one of the editors/authors).